# How to count specific string elements in list on dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, group-by, count

I have this list:

```
mylist = ['pages', 'disable', 'sensitive', 'application', 'screen', 'login', 'dynamic', 'frida', 'use', 'capture', 'stronger', 'flag_secure', 'strengthen', 'default', 'registration', 'obfuscate', 'anti', 'feature', 'protection', 'blurring', 'appsview', 'instrumentation', 'recent', 'paste', 'copy', 'exported', 'improve', 'mechanism', 'device', 'encryption', 'information', 'version', 'code', 'components', 'restrict', 'access', 'data', 'adding', 'debugger', 'otp', 'runtime', 'server', 'instrument', 'ensure', 'input', 'link', 'special', 'magisk', 'magic', 'obfuscation']
```

And I have this data frame which contained a bunch of strings:

```
0                       Implement stronger root detection and adding debugger or dynamic instrument detection at runtime. 
1                                                                 Strengthen root detection and implement Frida detection.
2                                                                           Implement code obfuscation to the application.
3                                                                   Disable screen capture by default and use FLAG_SECURE.
4                                                                            Implement screen blurring on the Recent Apps view.
```

How can I count the occurrences of each element in mylist on the data frame and sort it by its value counts?

This is kind of what I would like to get as result:

```
Word        Count
pages         31
disable       25
sensitive      6
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why is there the number `0` in `mylist`? Should the numbers be ignored?

Comment: Oh, just ignore the numbers..

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output doesn't match for the given sample data.

You can start by splitting the column on space, then `strip` off any left over white spaces or fullstops and commas, then explode it, then call `value_counts` and `reindex` on the list, finally drop `NaN` values, and sort the values in descending order.

It  assumes `case-sensitive` counts.

```py
#df is the dataframe, and text is the column name
>>> result=(df['text']
        .str
        .split()
        .apply(lambda x: [i.strip(' .,') for i in x])
        .explode()
        .value_counts()
        .reindex(mylist)
        .dropna()
        .sort_values(ascending=False))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> result
screen         2.0
application    1.0
dynamic        1.0
use            1.0
capture        1.0
stronger       1.0
default        1.0
blurring       1.0
code           1.0
adding         1.0
debugger       1.0
runtime        1.0
instrument     1.0
obfuscation    1.0
Name: text, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question well. This example will go for every word in `mylist` and counts occurrences in dataframe `df` (`df["col1"]` is your columns with strings):

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame({"Word": mylist})
df_out["Count"] = df_out["Word"].apply(
    lambda x: df["col1"]
    .apply(lambda z: sum(x in w for w in z.lower().split()))
    .sum()
)
print(df_out[df_out.Count > 0].sort_values(by="Count", ascending=False))
```

Prints:

```
           Word  Count
4        screen      2
1       disable      1
13      default      1
42   instrument      1
40      runtime      1
38     debugger      1
37       adding      1
32         code      1
22       recent      1
19     blurring      1
12   strengthen      1
3   application      1
11  flag_secure      1
10     stronger      1
9       capture      1
8           use      1
7         frida      1
6       dynamic      1
49  obfuscation      1
```